# Why PriorityQueue.peek() returns null, when PriorityQueue.size() > 0

Tags: android, null, size, priority-queue, peek

I have a problem when PriorityQueue.peek() returns `null` when PriorityQueue.size() > 0 on android.

[image]

I think this could be device issue. 
Does anybody have something in mind?

Comment: Going by the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#peek()), `peek` will only return `null` when it is the head element or when the queue is empty. I see that your `push` method checks for `null`, but are you sure that there is no other possibility to push a `null` into the queue? Could you as a log output for the head element, or debug? And please post a minimal, runnable example that produces the error instead of an image, so that people can try it.

Comment: Head of queue must be null

Comment: Thanks for answers. The only one scenario is possible that the head of queue is null. Need to find out how that happened.

Comment: The `compare` method in your `JobComparator` has a problem. If `lhs.priority` is , say, `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (or something close to that) and `rhs.priority` is a positive number, then `lhs.priority() - rhs.priority()` will result in integer overflow and you'll get the wrong answer. The correct way to do this is `return lhs.priority().compareTo(rhs.priority());`

Answer (score 0):

I see two following solutions:

- Replace **jobs.peek() != null** with **jobs.size() > 0** - you're interested in the size, right?
- Check what's inside **jobs** queue. Because based on Java documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) - **peek()** should retrieve "<...> the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.". So, either this queue is empty, or there is a element with a value of **null** inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After some time, the issue was solved. Basically it was problem with concurrency. Changing PriorityQueue.java to PriorityBlockingQueue.java solved it.